# How to run a command in a shell script just after it closes

Tags: shell

I'm writing a very simple shell script that makes some changes with the java version before opening a program, I already got that but I don't know how to make it undo it just after the program is closed.

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Roda o meu EP fazendo as alterações necessárias no Java, passando-o para a versão 8

#Faz
sudo apt remove open-jdk-11
sudo apt install open-jdk-8

#Roda
java MeuEPOrientadoaObjetos.jar

#Desfaz
sudo apt remove open-jdk-8
sudo apt install open-jdk-11
```

Comment: Instead of completely uninstalling one version and installing another, have you considered just leaving both installed and using `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java MeuEPOrientadoaObjetos.jar` or equivalent to run with a specific version?

Comment: It looks like your shell script is doing exactly what you want.  Or do you mean that you want to replace the java package just after your process begins, but before it finishes?